# Can't access database helper from second class

Tags: java, android, database

I have made CurrentChanceDatabse class in my app. It extends SQLiteOpenHelper. I have made some methods to assess tables and data.
When I access the CurrentChanceDatabase class with the following code, it works perfectly fine in the MainActivity(the default one which starts when the app is launched). All the methods work fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CurrentChanceDatabase db;  //this line
//more declarations
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new CurrentChanceDatabase(this);  //and this line
//more onCreate functions
}
```

Now, I want to access the same database from my second activity. I use the same two lines to connect to my database class, but the app crashes when the second activity launches. I have explained at the end that what I aim to do.

The code and logcat:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.snehit.probablity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CurrentChanceDatabase db;
EditText nameOfExperiment;
EditText noOfOutcomes;
Button ContinueBt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new CurrentChanceDatabase(this);
    ContinueBt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continueButtton);
    registerExperimentFunction();
    db.deleteAllData();  //see the very end of this question to know about this
    force(); //continues to the seconnd class without entring any experiment. will be used for debugging once the app works.

}

public void force(){
    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.force);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CurrentChanceDatabase.class);
            db.close();
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

public void registerExperimentFunction(){
   ContinueBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           nameOfExperiment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameOfExperiment);
           noOfOutcomes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noOfChance);
           String nameOfExperimentString = nameOfExperiment.getText().toString();
           Integer noOfOutcomesInt = Integer.parseInt(noOfOutcomes.getText().toString());
           Boolean success = db.registerExperiment(nameOfExperimentString, noOfOutcomesInt);
           if (success)
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Done Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           else

               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"UnDone UnSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CurrentChanceDatabase.class);
           db.close();
           startActivity(myIntent);

       }
   });
}

}
```

AddNames.java

```
package com.example.snehit.probablity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Created by Snehit on 6/10/2017.
 */
public class AddNames extends AppCompatActivity {
CurrentChanceDatabase db;
LinearLayout ll;
EditText editText;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_names);
    db = new CurrentChanceDatabase(this);
    addTextBox();
}


public void addTextBox(){
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    Cursor res = db.getAllChance();
    //StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    String chance = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("CHANCE"));
    Integer chanceInt = Integer.parseInt(chance);
    //buffer.append(res.getString(0) + "\n");
    for(int i=0;i<chanceInt;i++)
    {
        editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setHint("Name here");
       ll.addView(editText);
    }
}
}
```

CurrentChanceDatabse.java

```
package com.example.snehit.probablity;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Snehit on 6/9/2017.
  */
public class CurrentChanceDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "probablity.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "experiments";

public CurrentChanceDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,CHANCE TEXT, COMPLETED INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public boolean registerExperiment(String name, Integer chance){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("NAME", name);
    contentValues.put("CHANCE", chance);
    contentValues.put("COMPLETED", 0);

    long result =  db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Integer deleteData(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
}

public void deleteAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("vacuum");
}

public Cursor getAllChance(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from where COMPLETED = 0" + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}

}
```

add_names.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.snehit.probablity.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nameOfExperiment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="No. of outcomes"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameOfExperiment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/noOfChance"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Continue"
    android:id="@+id/continueButtton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Force continue"
    android:id="@+id/force"
    android:layout_below="@+id/continueButtton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />
```

Logcat error when the continue button is pressed on the MainActivity:

```
799/com.example.snehit.probablity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.snehit.probablity, PID: 1799
                                                                         android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.snehit.probablity/com.example.snehit.probablity.CurrentChanceDatabase}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
                                                                             at com.example.snehit.probablity.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-10 21:43:46.216 795-807/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.snehit.probablity/.MainActivity
```

This error does not come when the database class loads from the MainActivity class.

What I want to do

The user registers an experiment from activity_main.xml(MainActivity.java). The name, along with the number of chances is put into the databse when the user taps continue. Along with the database functions, an intent is also passed which launches the AddNames.java. This activity gets from the database the no. of chances from the database for the uncompleted experiment* and creates the same no. of EditTexts in the add_names.xml so the user can name it.

*Uncompleted experiment/deleteAllData(); - When a user has named all chances of an experiment, it will be marked completed, and the 'COMPLETED' value in the table will be increased from 0 to 1. This functionality was meant to be added in the AddNames.java, but since that thing refused to even launch, I haven't yet put that code. When a new experiment is added from the MainActivity.java, its 'COMPLETED' value is zero. All other experiments will have 'COMPLETED' value of 1. (the code for this thing will be put once the development progresses). So, to ensure that there is only on experiment with 'COMPLETED' value of 0, I delete all entries when the app starts. And to get the uncompleted experiments, I query the database with the 'WHERE COMPLETED = 0'.
Thank You!

Edit:

My Android manifest xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.snehit.probablity">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



<activity android:name="com.example.snehit.probablity.AddNames" android:label="@string/app_name">


</activity>
```

I had forgoten to add this before...

Thank You again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error myself after using the debugging tools in the ide. The error is in the MainActivity.java, where I have set the button onClick function for the continue button.

The code for the intent should be

`Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNames.class);`

My initial code launches the CurrentChanceDatabase.java on click, which I don't want to do.

Plus, the code for getting to number of chances for the uncompleted experiment in AddNames.java class, in the addTextBox() function is wrong. The no. of chances must the retrieved with a while loop, with `res.moveToNext()` as the condition. In the loop, the no.of chances must be retrieved and casted to integer, to be used in the loop which adds the text boxes.

Answer (score 2):

> but the app crashes when the second activity launches.

It clearly means that the second activity `AddNames` was not registered within the project's manifest. Therefore getting this error:

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.snehit.probablity/com.example.snehit.probablity.CurrentChanceDatabase}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Make sure that you register the `AddNames` activity in the manifest

---

Add this to your `manifest.xml`:

`<activity android:name="AddNames" >`

Comment: I had declared the activity in the manifest file already. I had forgotten to post the code for the manifest. See the edited question. Plus, the error asks to declare the CurrentChanceActivity.java (and not the AddNames.java, as you asked me to do). On declaring the Current chance.java, I get an error regarding 'matching constructor not found'.